# How can I expose my data model in a transactional form?

Tags: c#, .net, data-access-layer

Some software currently being written has a requirement for the data model to be transactional, implementing CRUD operations. (get a copy of data, make changes, submit it atomically, get fault messages for failures, etc.)

Is there a well documented design pattern for something like this? Maybe a library?

NOTE: I'm using C#/.NET 4.0

PLEASE NOTE, my data model is POCO! not SQL or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ORM like Entity Framework, nHibernate etc

They have built in change tracking system and implement "Unit of Work" pattern(single transaction)

Comment: @Firoso nHibernate supports In-Memory SQLite database which supports transactions